Showing mouse position on ContourPlot curve dynamically
This is a function that shows mouse position on ContourPlot curve dynamically, but it seems to have wasted a lot of computing resources, making the program very sluggish.
What can I do to make it more smooth and have better performance?
a = 1
h = 1
b = 1
g = 1
A1[x_] := 2*a*b*Cos[x] - 2*g*b
B1[x_] := 2*a*b*Sin[x]
C1[x_] := g^2 + b^2 + a^2 - h^2 - 2*a*g*Cos[x]
f1[x_, y_] := A1[x]*Cos[y] + B1[x]*Sin[y] - C1[x]
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}, closestPoint, f1, mousePos, x, y}, 
  f1[x_, y_] := A1[x]*Cos[y] + B1[x]*Sin[y] - C1[x]; 
  EventHandler[
   Dynamic[Module[{distanceFunction, result}, 
     mousePos = MousePosition["Graphics"];
     If[mousePos === None, mousePos = pt]; 
     distanceFunction = (x - mousePos[[1]])^2 + (y - 
          mousePos[[2]])^2;
     result = Minimize[{distanceFunction, f1[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}];
     closestPoint = {x, y} /. result[[2]]; 
     Show[ContourPlot[
       f1[x, y] == 0, {x, -Pi/2, 3/2 Pi}, {y, -Pi/2, 3/2 Pi}, 
       ContourStyle -> Blue, PlotPoints -> 10, Frame -> True], 
      Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[closestPoint]}], 
      PlotRange -> {{-Pi/2, 3/2 Pi}, {-Pi/2, 3/2 Pi}}, 
      AspectRatio -> 1, 
      PlotLabel -> 
       Style["RedpointPosition: " <> ToString[closestPoint], 12, 
        Bold] ]]], {"MouseMoved" :> (pt = 
       MousePosition["Graphics"])}]], TrackedSymbols :> {pt}]



Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that PlotHighlighting is available for CountourPlot (in which case you could use the same answer as in your previous question).
However, you can still use your idea with MousePosition. The trick is to first generate a ContourPlot, extract the points, and then precalculate the NearestFunction. Here is a minimal example:
{a, h, b, g} = {1, 1, 1, 1};
A1[x_] := 2*a*b*Cos[x] - 2*g*b
B1[x_] := 2*a*b*Sin[x]
C1[x_] := g^2 + b^2 + a^2 - h^2 - 2*a*g*Cos[x]
f1[x_, y_] := A1[x]*Cos[y] + B1[x]*Sin[y] - C1[x]

cp = ContourPlot[f1[x, y] == 0, {x, -Pi/2, 3/2 Pi}, {y, -Pi/2, 3/2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 50];

(* Extract coordinates and construct NearestFunction *)
nf = Nearest[Catenate@Cases[Normal@p, Line[pts_] :> pts, All]];

(* Helper function *)
nff[pts_] := First@nf[pts];
nff[None] = {};

Show[{cp, Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, 
 Point[Dynamic@nff[MousePosition["Graphics"]]]}]}, 
 PlotLabel -> Dynamic[nff[MousePosition["Graphics"]]]]



thank you so much for your answer, this help me a lot.
